# Which event or index should I listen in order to get a new referenda in "started" (open to vote) status?

Tags: governance

As described, I would like to construct a listener to be alerted when a new referenda has just started. Currently, I am using mostly Subscan API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With PolkadotJS you can be listening the events as it is explained [here in the docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/system-events):

```js
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');

async function main () {
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:9900');
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

  // Subscribe to system events via storage
  api.query.system.events((events) => {
    console.log(`\nReceived ${events.length} events:`);

    // Loop through the Vec<EventRecord>
    events.forEach((record) => {
      // Extract the phase, event and the event types
      const { event, phase } = record;
      const types = event.typeDef;
      console.log(event.toHuman());
    });
  });
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(-1);
});
```

When a referendum begins you query the event [Started](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L459).

If you want to get when a proposal is created you query the event [Proposed](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/22d40c761a985482f93bbbea5ba4199bdba74f8e/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L498).

See [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L451) all the rest of events from the Governance Pallet.

The event you will get from the code above will looks like this:

```json
{
  method: 'Proposed',
  section: 'democracy',
  index: '0x0d00',
  data: { proposalIndex: '2', deposit: '3,333,333,300' }
}
```

In Kusama we have already deployed the new protocol for governance [OpenGov](https://guide.kusama.network/docs/learn-opengov). In this case we have to take a look in the [events form the Referenda pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/referenda/src/lib.rs#L256).

For your specific question we have to query the event `DecisionStarted` that is triggered when a referendum has moved into the deciding phase.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is useful to listen to referenda on Polkadot (Gov1.0), but what about referenda created on Kusama (OpenGov)? What pallet/event is the relevant in that case? Note that this will be the case for Polkadot soon too.

Comment: thanks for updating the answer with the complete info :)